# ExtJs Actioncolum tooltip display clicking on image instead of Mouseover

Tags: extjs

I am new into ExtJs, I am using one of column as Actioncolumn in ExtJs Grid, My requirement is show tooltip on Mousehover event, But I am getting tool tip on image click event,  I am using following code,

I am using Ext.QuickTips.init();

```js
{
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 30,
                sortable: false,
                menuDisabled: true,
                items: [{
                    icon: '/delete.gif',
                    
                    getClass: function(value,meta,record,rowIx,colIx, store) {
                       this.items[0].tooltip = 'Delete Record ';
                       return 'some-class-name'; // or something if needed
            },
                    
                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                       store.removeAt(rowIndex);
                    }
                }],              
                
                
                
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tooltip` config directly: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-tooltip

Here is an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17o2

Comment: Thank you it works :), Actually it was browser issue it was giving problem on chrome, but it is working on IE.